# Using Dates in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date-arithmetic

I am trying to get only the month of August in my database and then count how many times there has been a performance during August however I can't figure out how to do it.

I have given the code which I have created so far.

```sql
SELECT f.FILM_NAME, COUNT(p.PERFORMANCE_DATE), SUM(p.TAKINGS), p.PERFORMANCE_DATE
FROM A2_PERFORMANCE p, A2_FILM f 
WHERE p.PERFORMANCE_DATE LIKE TO_DATE('08-2021', 'MM-YY')
GROUP BY f.FILM_NAME, p.PERFORMANCE_DATE
ORDER BY f.FILM_NAME
```

I am currently trying to achieve this:

```sql
-- FILM_NAME                   Performances Total Takings         
-- --------------------------- ------------ ----------------------
-- It Happened One Night       39               £63,571 
-- Modern Times                38               £58,332 
-- Parasite                    23               £37,195 
-- Knives Out                  22               £34,362 
-- Citizen Kane                25               £32,711 
-- The Wizard of Oz            18               £21,716 
-- Avengers: Endgame           18               £17,081
```

Comment: First you need to check the output of `TO_DATE('08-2021', 'MM-YY')`. Then you may imagine yourself a DBMS and decide, how would you treat a date to be "like" other date. And finally use `some_date >= date '2021-08-01' and some_date < date '2021-09-01'`, because in Oracle `date` is a misleading name for `datetime` and `between` will filter out dates after the midnight of the last day.

Comment: You have SQL Developer in the title of your question. But the question has nothing to do with it; SQL Developer is just the graphical interface you use, and the question isn't about it. Rather, the question is about Oracle SQL. I edited your title accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert your dates to string and compare them to '08-2021' (not in the way you did - you must apply formatting to the dates themselves first), but that is inefficient.

You can also truncate the dates to the beginning of the month and compare to date `'2021-08-01'`, but that is also inefficient.

"Inefficiency" comes from two sources, one smaller and one really big. The smaller one is having to apply functions to data from your table. The really big one has to do with indexing: if your queries often filter based on dates, then you would benefit from indexing the date column - but the index can't be used if your filters apply a function to the date column first.

So, how to do it? Best (especially if your "dates" may have time-of-day component other than midnight) is something like this:

```
...
where p.performance_date >= date '2021-08-01'
  and p.performance_date <  date '2021-09-01'
...
```

Note that it's always two inequalities, the first one is non-strict and the second is strict.

If instead you use `performance_date between [Aug 1] and [Sep 1]` (in pseudo-code), this will give the wrong answer - this makes the second inequality also non-strict, so you will include performances with a date of Sept. 1, if they are saved in the db with a time-of-day of midnight. And `between [Aug 1] and [Aug 31]` will miss everything on August 31 with a time-of-day OTHER THAN midnight.

Best not to use BETWEEN and instead to use two explicit inequalities, as I have shown.

Comment: Hello, I have edited my question to be more precise on what I want to achieve if you want to possibly have a look and give assistance.

Thank You

Comment: @PeterNokes - I answered your question about how to filter for dates. Your edit doesn't change my answer. Now, you may not like that your query doesn't produce the desired result. That's a separate question. From a quick look I see that you included the performance date in the `GROUP BY` clause. That makes no sense. Remove it from there and see if that gives you what you need.

Comment: @PeterNokes - then, you will have to remove the date from `SELECT` too (it has no business being there either: the query is for the month, not for individual dates).

Answer (score 1):

You are currently doing:

```
WHERE p.PERFORMANCE_DATE LIKE TO_DATE('08-2021', 'MM-YY')
```

You are providing a 4-digit year value (2021) but have only given YY in the format model, not YYYY. Now, Oracle by default is lenient about this sort of thing - unhelpfully so, some might say - so this will work in this case. But it's not good practice, and `TO_DATE('08-2021', 'MM-YYYY')` would be better. Either way, that will give you midnight on the the first day of that month. You can provide that a bit more simply with a [date literal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-8F4B3F82-8821-4071-84D6-FBBA21C05AC1): `DATE '2021-08-01'`.

`LIKE` is [a pattern-matching condition](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Pattern-matching-Conditions.html#GUID-0779657B-06A8-441F-90C5-044B47862A0A), and compares strings, *not* dates. You are forcing an implicit conversion of both your column value and the fixed date you provided to strings, using your session's NLS_DATE_FORMAT setting. You also aren't including any wildcard characters, making it equivalent to `=`. So with a common NLS setting, you are really doing:

```
WHERE TO_CHAR(p.PERFORMANCE_DATE, 'DD-MON-RR') = TO_CHAR(DATE '2021-08-01', 'DD-MON-RR')
```

With that NLS setting you would match any values on August 1st - though it would match data from 1921 etc. as well as 2021, if you had any. With a more precise NLS setting you might be doing:

```
WHERE TO_CHAR(p.PERFORMANCE_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MM:SS') = TO_CHAR(DATE '2021-08-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

which would only match values at exactly midnight on August 1st.

To match the whole month you *could* use an explicit mask, instead of the implicit conversion; and you only need to convert the column value, as you can supply the fixed value in the format you want anyway:

```
WHERE TO_CHAR(p.PERFORMANCE_DATE, 'YYYY-MM') = '2021-08'
```

or, if you prefer (I don't, but it's not my code):

```
WHERE TO_CHAR(p.PERFORMANCE_DATE, 'MM-YYYY') = '08-2021'
```

But that conversion will prevent a normal index on that column being used. I would suggest providing a date range to avoid any conversion:

```
WHERE p.PERFORMANCE_DATE >= DATE '2021-08-01'
AND p.PERFORMANCE_DATE < DATE '2021-09-01'
```

which will find all rows where that column is on or after midnight on August 1st, and *before* midnight on September 1st.

Comment: Hello, I have edited my question to be more precise on what I want to achieve if you want to possibly have a look and give assistance. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for all activities in august regardless of the year, you can convert your column to char of 'MON' and match it with 'AUG' :

```
SELECT f.FILM_NAME, COUNT(p.PERFORMANCE_DATE), SUM(p.TAKINGS),p.PERFORMANCE_DATE
FROM A2_PERFORMANCE p, A2_FILM f 
WHERE TO_CHAR(p.PERFORMANCE_DATE,'MON') ='AUG'
GROUP BY f.FILM_NAME, p.PERFORMANCE_DATE
ORDER BY f.FILM_NAME
```